# If I turned off the wireless display while my phone was still connected to my neighbor's TV, would it automatically disconnect from it?

Tags: wi-fi, security, external-display

I accidentally connected my phone to my neighbor's TV.

- I instantly turned off the wireless display, did my phone disconnect from his TV?
- If I turned on the wireless display again, will his TV automatically reconnect to my phone?
- If I disconnect my phone while it's still in a "connecting" state (not "connected" state), did I actually disconnect it from his TV?
- If he turned his TV off first before I managed to disconnect it from his TV and his TV disappeared from the wireless display list, did my phone automatically disconnect from his TV? And once he's turning his TV back, does it still connect to my phone?

Is my phone safe from this?